# Upgrading an older HP Pavilion laptop from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-8.1, bios

I'm updating someone's older HP Pavilion laptop from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, using Microsoft's Media Creation Tool.

I've created a recovery partition and made a complete system backup, in case anything goes awry.

For the best chance of success, I'm trying to update the system as much as possible, but I've run into...well, every problem:

- Windows Update says there's about 600mb of updates available, but fails to install them.
- HP Support Assistant says the laptop's entirely up to date, but I'm pretty sure it's not.
- The HP website simply lists the laptop as no longer supported; no driver, firmware, or BIOS updates are to be found there.
- HP advertises a way of updating the BIOS from the BIOS, but there's no option to do so in the BIOS.

I've read that BIOS versions predating Windows 10 sometimes refuse to play nice with the OS. The BIOS version currently installed is from 2012. The CPU driver is also old, from 2009.

Any ideas on how to proceed? The owner would like the laptop to have Windows 10, but I'm hesitant to perform the update if it has a high chance of failure. Also, if it does fail, should recovery from the new partition be relatively straightforward? This is my first time installing Windows 10. Let me know if any more information would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure why so many issues with the Windows 8.1 machine in terms of updates and drivers.  I updated a 2013 ThinkPad X230 running truly up to date Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 in 2015. Is the machine older than 2013?  That may be the issue.

Comment: @John, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure of the exact age of the laptop, but about a decade old would be a good guess. The system model is 'HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC', but I'm unfamiliar with HP's naming pattern.

Comment: A decade ago is 2013 (age of my X230) and it updated fine, and in fact, went on to run early Windows 11 Insider.  If you are hesitant to upgrade, I really do not have any suggestions.

Comment: "I've created a recovery partition and made a complete system backup, in case anything goes awry." If things go badly, only a drive image is likely to help. Also, Win 10 would be a waste of time, if it can even be installed, since "Windows 10 will reach end of support on October 14, 2025." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro

Comment: I have also run into this same issue. The fix was to download Win10 1909 ISO, extract to folder on the desktop and then run the setup.exe with internet disconnected. This forces a successful offline upgrade to Win10. From there, it still wouldn't take online updates to latest Win10 version, so I had to download Win10 2004 ISO, extract to folder on desktop and run setup.exe with no internet again. Once upgrade was complete, I was able to do online Win10 updates all the way up to 22H2. Strange I know, but that's what worked for me on an old HP Z240 upgrading from Win7.

Comment: Worth noting that I did perform BIOS upgrade prior to doing all the above. So worth downloading your HP Pavilion BIOS update file to USB and upgrading your BIOS first. If you go to the BIOS update section in your BIOS settings it should hopefully allow you to perform an internet update with cable plugged in.  It will say "Check for BIOS update with HP" or something like that. If not, then it will tell you what folder structure to use on a USB stick.

Comment: I've updated very old HQ laptops to Windows 10. They ran OK. Mine was from 2010. Many of the drivers were no longer available from HQ, but MS downloaded or used generic drivers that worked well enough and the laptop functioned fine, except for being slow. Windows 10 will download its own updates: you don't need to waste time updating Windows 8. Follow HPs own documentation for updating the BIOS. HQSA can't download drivers that aren't published so point 3 explains point 2.

Comment: The last few questions make me wonder why you're trying this. Tell the owner you do not feel confident updating this laptop as they have requested. It's a very old laptop, and it should be used as it currently is rather than taken someplace it is intended to be, for its own benefit and for its owners. Backups are only as "easy" as the method and tools used to create them and how they are intended to be restored from.

Comment: The reasons I am recommending this question be closed are as follows: You have asked several questions; this site requires a single question per post. Some of your questions are opinion based; this site does not allow opinions for answers. Some of your questions indicate there is information out there, but you haven't indicated that you've found or read that information and what the results of your doing so were. Some of your questions indicate you have done particular steps, but you don't give necessary details regarding what you've done.

Comment: You're not wrong for having this problem, so don't take it that way. We need questions to be a particular way: focused, specific, clear, with sufficient information, etc, in order to be answered. You can read the Help section to learn the why and suggestions for how as well.

Comment: @music2myear, thanks for letting me know. I think I basically forgot to ask my question, which was how to prepare a Windows 8.1 system for an in-place Windows 10 upgrade *when the manufacturer appears to have not only ended support but scrubbed its website of updates for the machine,* provided that the Windows 10 upgrade is even advisable in the first place. Maybe that is still a more...complexly-worded question than this site would like, however. Luckily, I think I've gotten enough info from the comments.

Comment: @Mastaxx, thanks for your comments. I've decided to leave the machine as is, but I have a feeling your workaround will come in handy one day.